# Overlapping Columns with IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, overlap

I'm really having a hard time with IE7 as it is making part of my page fluid where it should be fixed.  Works fine in every other browser but IE.

Here is the link... .  If you shrink the window you will see how the page gets all skewed.

Here is the css used to control the 2 columns, `left_body` being the left content and `right_body` the right column.

```
#left_body
{
    float: left;
    width: 900px;
}

#right_body
{
    padding-right: 5px;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Had position:relative, needed to be position:static